# Showing polyline coordinates in text input

Tags: leaflet, html

This is my code:

```
map.on("click", function(e) {
    var latlng = e.latlng;
    document.getElementById("lat1").value = latlng.lat;
    document.getElementById("lng1").value = latlng.lng;
    console.log(latlng);
});
```

How can I show all polyline coordinates, displaying in `console.log`, into text input?

[image]

Comment: What do you men by "text input"? Please edit your question and describe more in detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think they want to output every coordinate of line nodes to the textboxes (HTML textarea elements) below the map.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append to the contents of the input elements, not overwrite them, so your code becomes

```
map.on("click", function(e) {
  var latlng = e.latlng;
  document.getElementById("lat1").value += latlng.lat;
  document.getElementById("lng1").value += latlng.lng;
  console.log(latlng);
});
```

Note the `+=` instead of `=` in lines 2 and 3 of your function